# Scale square matrix in geometrical sense using python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scaling

I have an matrix (ndarray) with real values that I want to scale in a geometrical sense - that is expand the matrix's size while keeping the values as similar as possible. It can be viewed as scaling an image.

But my matrix is NOT an image. I have real values ranging from 8,000 to 50,000. As far as I know these values cannot represent anything from an usual image point of view.

I have searched the web for answers but every answer suggested using PIL or similar image processing libraries, that use standard pixel values that wouldn't accept my matrix.

So is there a way to scale a matrix containing any real numbers in the geometrical (or image) sense?

Is there a python library for that or list comprehension of some kind or someting similar?

Thank you.

Comment: _"list comprehension"_ - never the right solution when using numpy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're describing is 2D interpolation. Scipy provides an implementation in [`scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline.html)

```
from scipy.interpolate import RectBivariateSpline

# sample data
data = np.random.rand(8, 4)
width, height = data.shape
xs = np.arange(width)
ys = np.arange(height)

# target size and interpolation locations
new_width, new_height = width*2, height*2
new_xs = np.linspace(0, width-1, new_width)
new_ys = np.linspace(0, height-1, new_height)

# create the spline object, and use it to interpolate
spline = RectBivariateSpline(xs, ys, data) #, kx=1, ky=1) for linear interpolation
spline(new_xs, new_ys)
```